# R Geom Line, color and shape for the same figures

Tags: r, ggplot2, shapes, scale-color-manual

I used "scale_shape_manual" and "scale_color_manual" to color and shape 5 different variables, they are not on the same column. I want the legend to be just one merged, not separated, like the image.

[image: Reference]

I want the legend to be the shape colored by the color assigned. Any idea of how to do this?

I'm using pipelines. Here is the code:

```
underlag3 %>% 
  mutate_at(c('fjarrvarme', 'oljeeldning','ovrigt','fjarrvarme_komb',
              'gas','elvarme','bergvarme','bio'), as.numeric) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=ar)) +
  geom_line(aes(y=fjarrvarme), color="#000080") +
  geom_point(aes(y=fjarrvarme, shape="Fjarrvarme",color="Fjarrvarme")) +
  geom_line(aes(y=fjarrvarme_komb), color="#363636") +
  geom_point(aes(y=fjarrvarme_komb, shape="FjarrVarme Komb", color="FjarrVarme Komb")) +
  geom_line(aes(y=elvarme), color="#544C4A") +
  geom_point(aes(y=elvarme, shape="elvarme", color="elvarme")) +
  geom_line(aes(y=bio), color="black") +
  geom_point(aes(y=bio, shape="bio", color="bio")) +
  geom_line(aes(y=bergvarme), color="#5097A4") +
  geom_point(aes(y=bergvarme, shape="bergvarme", shape="color")) +
  geom_line(aes(y=oljeeldning), color="#787276") +
  geom_point(aes(y=oljeeldning, shape="oljeeldning", color="oljeeldning")) +
  geom_line(aes(y=gas), color="#4682b4") +
  geom_point(aes(y=gas, shape="gas", color="gas")) +
  geom_line(aes(y=ovrigt), color="#222021") +
  geom_point(aes(y=ovrigt, shape="ovrigt", color="ovrigt")) +
  scale_x_continuous(n.breaks = 41) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c('Fjarrvarme' = 17, 'FjarrVarme Komb' = 18,
                                'elvarme' = 4, 'bio' = 16,
                                'bergvarme' = 16, 'oljeeldning' = 15,
                                'gas' = 16, 'ovrigt' = 16)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c('Fjarrvarme' = "#000080", 'FjarrVarme Komb' = "#363636",
                                'elvarme' = "#544C4A", 'bio' = "black",
                                'bergvarme' = "#5097A4", 'oljeeldning' = "#787276",
                                'gas' = "#4682b4", 'ovrigt' = "#222021"))
```

Comment: Does it resolve if you assign the same name to both scales? e..g `scale_shape_manual(name = "my legend", ....`

Comment: This also looks like a prime example where your life will be made simpler if you reshape your data longer and assign the column to color & shape.

Answer (score 2):

```
library(tidyverse)
mtcars |>
  pivot_longer(disp:qsec) |>
  ggplot(aes(mpg, value, color = name, shape = name)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c('disp' = 0, 'drat' = 1, 'hp' = 2,
                                'qsec' = 3, 'wt' = 4),
                     name = "my legend") +
  scale_color_manual(values = c('disp' = "blue", 'drat' = "red", 'hp' = "green",
                                'qsec' = "gray20", 'wt' = "gray80"),
                     name = "my legend")
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This type of problems generally has to do with reshaping the data. The format should be the long format and the data is in wide format. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185252/reshaping-data-frame-from-wide-to-long-format) on how to reshape the data from wide to long format.

I will first create named vectors for the legend labels, colors and shapes.

```r
nms <- c('fjarrvarme', 'fjarrvarme_komb', 'elvarme', 'bio',
         'bergvarme', 'oljeeldning', 'gas', 'ovrigt')
labls <- setNames(c('Fjarrvarme', 'Fjarrvarme Komb', 'elvarme', 'bio',
                    'bergvarme', 'oljeeldning', 'gas', 'ovrigt'), nms)
clrs <- setNames(c("#000080", "#363636", "#544C4A", "black", "#5097A4", 
                   "#787276", "#4682b4", "#222021"), nms)
shps <- setNames(c(17, 18, 4, 16, 16, 15, 16, 16), nms)
```

<sup>Created on 2023-11-26 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Now plot the data with the data example in the end of this post.

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages({
  library(tidyverse)
})

underlag3 %>%
  pivot_longer(-ar, names_to = "Variable") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = ar, y = value, color = Variable, shape = Variable)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() +
  scale_shape_manual(labels = labls, values = shps) +
  scale_color_manual(labels = labls, values = clrs) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-11-26 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

## Data example

```r
set.seed(2023)
underlag3 <- sapply(seq_along(labls), \(mu) cumsum(rnorm(20, mean = mu))) %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  mutate(ar = seq_along(V1)) %>%
  setNames(c(nms, 'ar'))
```

<sup>Created on 2023-11-26 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>